# Cyclic Quadrilaterals Advanced

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

> $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral; $x,y,z$ are the distances of $A$ from the lines $BD, BC, CD$ respectively. Prove that $$\frac{BD}x = \frac{BC}y + \frac{CD}z.$$

I guess this can be done by multiple application of cot rule. I found a really beautiful solution in a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A', B', D'$ be the orthogonal projections of $A$ onto the lines $BD, BC, CD$ respectively, so $AA' = x, \, AB' = y, \, AD' = z$. Then the three points $A', B', D'$ are collinear (Simson's line).

1. Triangle $ABB'$ is similar to triangle $ADD'$. Therefore,
   $$\frac{AB}{AD}= \frac{AB'}{AD'}=\frac{y}{z}$$
2. Triangle $ADC$ is similar to triangle $AA'B'$. Therefore
   $$\frac{AC}{AD}= \frac{AB'}{AD'}=\frac{y}{x}$$
3. Apply Ptolemy's theorem to $ABCD$
   $$BD \cdot AC = BC \cdot AD + CD \cdot AB$$
   and plug 
   $$AB = \frac{y}{z}\, AD, \,\, AC = \frac{y}{x} \, AD$$ so
   $$BD \cdot \frac{y}{x} \, AD  = BC \cdot AD + CD \cdot \frac{y}{z}\, AD$$ which simplifies to 
   $$\frac{BD}{x} = \frac{BC}{y} + \frac{CD}{z}$$

**Yet another solution:**

Let $A', B', D'$ be the orthogonal projections of $A$ onto the lines $BD, BC, CD$ respectively, so $AA' = x, \, AB' = y, \, AD' = z$.

1. Then $A', B', D'$ lie on the Simson line and let $H$ be the orthogonal projection of $A$ on the Simson line $B'D'$ and let its length be $h = AH$;
2. Triangle $AA'B'$ similar to triangle $ADC$ and moreover $AH = h$ and $AB' = y$ are corresponding similar altitudes. Hence
   $$\frac{BC}{y} = \frac{A'D'}{h};$$
3. Triangle $AA'D'$ similar to triangle $ABC$ and moreover $AH = h$ and $AD' = z$ are corresponding similar altitudes. Hence
   $$\frac{CD}{z} = \frac{A'B'}{h}$$
4. Triangle $AB'D'$ similar to triangle $ABD$ and moreover $AH = h$ and $AA' = x$ are corresponding similar altitudes. Hence
   $$\frac{BD}{x} = \frac{B'D'}{h}$$
5. Collinearity of $A', B' D'$ equivalent to 
   $$B'D' = A'B' + A'D' $$ which means
   $$B'D' = \frac{BD}{x} \, h = A'B' + A'D'=  \frac{CD}{z}\, h +  \frac{BC}{y} \, h$$ and after cancelling out $h$ on both sides of the equation
   $$\frac{BD}{x} =  \frac{BC}{y} + \frac{CD}{z}$$

Answer (score 3):

That identity can be seen as a consequence of the properties of [circle inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry). We have that $A$ lies on the circumcircle of $BCD$ (with radius $R$), hence by considering a circle inversion with respect to $\Gamma_A$, circle centered at $A$ through the circumcenter of $BCD$, we have that the images $B',C',D'$ of $B,C,D$ are collinear. Let $d$ be the distance of $A$ from the line through $B',C',D'$.

[image]

We clearly have $B'C'+C'D'=B'D'$ by collinearity, so 
$$\frac{B'C'}{d}+\frac{C'D'}{d} = \frac{B'D'}{d}$$

On the other hand, $ABC$ and $AC'B'$ are similar triangles, hence $$\frac{B'C'}{d}=\frac{BC}{y}$$ 
and the claim readily follows.

Comment: Thanks. Had some trouble understanding but got it in the end.